# Não está gerando os 1000 números aleatórios necessários

Tags: c, c++, operadores, random

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em C que gere aleatoriamente mil números e que no final apareça o maior e menor entre eles. Para isso, estou usando o `rand()`.

Mas estou com um problema. Quando eu executo só é gerado menos de 300 números e não de 0 a 1000. Mas sim de 707 a 1000.

Vejam abaixo o que eu fiz:

```
include stdio.h
include stdlib.h
include windows.h

main(){
   int numero,numero2;
   int total1 = 0;
   int total2 = 1001;

   for (numero = 1; numero != 1001; numero++){
       numero2 = rand () % 1000;
       printf("Numero %d: %d \n ",numero,numero2);

       if (numero2 > total1){
           total1 = numero2;
       }

       if (numero2 < total2){
           total2 = numero2;
       }
   }

   printf("\n");
   printf("O maior numero e: %d \n\n",total1);
   printf("O menor numero e: %d \n\n",total2);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: seria bom começo, indentar o código corretamente, assim fica mais fácil para todos saber o erro, até facilita a sua vida

Comment: e o erro esta na parte do return 0 no meio de um if que ao meu ver deveria estar fora do for, e mesmo assim sua aplicação não vai funcionar... 
eu aconselharia fazer do zero

Comment: É linguagem C ou C++ ?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Seu código tem vários erros de sintaxe e não estava (antes de editarem, o que não deve ser feito) bem desorganizado, isto faz com que fique difícil entendê-lo. Mesmo você que o escreveu acaba se perdendo nele. A nomenclatura das variáveis também ajudaria descrever melhor o que o código faz.

Mas o problema principal foi o uso indevido do operador `!=` (operador que testa a **diferença**, ou seja se os operandos são diferentes entre si, que possui **qualquer** diferença de uma para outro) quando deveria usar `<` (operador que testa se o primeiro operando é **menor que** o segundo). O primeiro faz enquanto for diferente, ou seja é para não fazer nada. Não sei como estava fazendo alguma coisa. O segundo operador, como a leitura dele mesmo descreve faz enquanto "for menor que". Então `numero` começa em 1 e vai contando até que ele chegue em 1001. Enquanto ele for menor que 1001, vai repetindo, portanto vai repetir mil vezes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int numero, numero2;
    int total1 = 0;
    int total2 = 1001;
       
    for (numero = 1; numero < 1001; numero++) {
        numero2 = rand () % 1000;
        printf("Numero %d: %d \n ", numero, numero2);
        if (numero2 > total1) total1 = numero2;
        if (numero2 < total2) total2 = numero2;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("O maior numero e: %d \n\n",total1);
    printf("O menor numero e: %d \n\n",total2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uAuFUZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/busaiglz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/MinInRandom.c).

Nele fiz um pouco diferente, coloquei o [`srand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) para começar semear de forma um pouco melhor os número pseudoaleatórios.

Comment: Ah sim entendi. Mais uma dúvida.. O operador != é a mesma coisa que < ?

E a organização dele interfere em algo na hora do computador ler as linhas e executar o programa ou é mais questão de organização? Obrigado.

Comment: Não precisa fazer já, mas se resolveu o seu problema você pode aceitar a resposta como a correta. Veja em [tour] como funciona. Quando tiver reputação suficiente (falta pouco) você poderá votar em todas as perguntas e respostas do site que achar interessante para você, mesmo as que não estão relacionadas com perguntas suas.

Comment: Beleza!!! Muito obrigado, a sua ajuda foi muito útil. Gostaria de aceitar essa resposta, é uma pena que eu não consiga nesse momento. Mas assim que isso for liberado para mim farei ok? vlew!!

Comment: Editei para melhorar a resposta. A organização em geral não interfere para o computador, mas complica muito a leitura e isso é que realmente é importante me programação. De qualquer forma, o seu código estava tão desorganizado que tinha erros que talvez você nem estivesse percebendo. Tem algumas desorganizações que podem virar defeito. Eu acho que aceitar a resposta você pode à qualquer momento. Você pode fazer já ou esperar pra ver se aparece uma resposta melhor ainda. Aceitação você só pode fazer uma resposta por pergunta que seja sua. E pode trocar depois se desejar e tiver algo melhor.

Comment: vou criar uma pergunta com a pergunta do andré
Ah sim entendi. Mais uma dúvida.. O operador != é a mesma coisa que < ? E a organização dele interfere em algo na hora do computador ler as linhas e executar o programa ou é mais questão de organização? Obrigado.

Comment: O operador != verifica se os valores comparados são diferentes, enquanto que o < verifica se o primeiro valor é menor que o segundo.
Com relação a organização do código é para ficar mais fácil de você (ou outra pessoa) entender o código depois e poder modificá-lo.