# Operadores, ordem, relevância, como é lido e prioridade

Tags: c, operadores

Me deparei com a seguinte pergunta em um comentário da seguinte [Questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39371/n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-gerando-os-1000-n%C3%BAmeros-aleat%C3%B3rios-necess%C3%A1rios)

> Mais uma dúvida.. O operador != é a mesma coisa que < ?

Então decidi criar uma resposta explicando direitinho para tirar duvidas ou ensinar quem não sabe.

Comment: `(!=) == (<); //true`
`(!=) === (<); //false`

Comment: @AntonyAlkmim ?!?!?!

Comment: @bigown nao entendeu meu comentario! Eu quis dizer que na verdade `!=` não é a mesma coisa que `<`, mas dependendo do que for fazer... Exemplo: para X menor 3, todos os valores serão diferente de 3. Mas para X diferente de 3, os valores podem ser tanto maiores quanto menores que 3.

Comment: A segunda parte do comentário citado nesta pergunta é sobre outra coisa, foi dito porque o código dele estava muito desorganizado.

Comment: eu to respondendo =/

Comment: Você acha que alguma resposta merece a aceitação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O operador `!=` não é a mesma coisa que `<`. O operador `!=` significa desigualdade, enquanto que o `<` significa menor-que.

De acordo com [isto aqui](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence%20aqui), eis a precedência dos operadores:

#### Precedência 1 (avaliados primeiro, da esquerda para a direita):

- `var++`: Incremento pós-fixado.
- `var--`: Decremento pós-fixado.
- `func(param)`: Chamada de função.
- `array[indice]`: Acesso a índices de um array.
- `var.membro`: Acesso a membros de `union`s ou `struct`s.
- `var->membro`: Acesso a membros de `union`s ou `struct`s através de ponteiros.
- `(tipo){lista}: Literal composto (C99 ou superior)

#### Precedência 2 (avaliados da direita para a esquerda):

- `++var`: Incremento pré-fixado.
- `--var`: Decremento pré-fixado.
- `+var`: Sinal de positivo unário. Na prática não faz nada.
- `-var`: Sinal de negativo unário. Inverte o sinal do operando.
- `!var`: Operador NÃO lógico.
- `~var`: Operador NÃO bitwise.
- `(tipo) var`: Cast de tipos.
- `*var`: Indireção de ponteiros.
- `&var`: Operador de endereço.
- `sizeof var`: Operador de tamanho na memória.
- `_Alignof var`: Operador de alinhamento (C11 ou superior).

#### Precedência 3 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a * b`: Multiplicação.
- `a / b`: Quociente da divisão.
- `a % b`: Resto da divisão.

#### Precedência 4 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a + b`: Soma.
- `a - b`: Subtração.

#### Precedência 5 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a << b`: Deslocamento de bits para a esquerda.
- `a >> b`: Deslocamento de bits para a direita.

#### Precedência 6 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a > b`: Maior-que.
- `a < b`: Menor-que.
- `a >= b`: Maior-ou-igual.
- `a <= b`: Menor-ou-igual.

#### Precedência 7 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a == b`: Igual.
- `a != b`: Diferente.

#### Precedência 8 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a & b`: Operador E bitwise.

#### Precedência 9 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a ^ b`: Operador OU EXCLUSIVO bitwise.

#### Precedência 10 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a | b`: Operador OU bitwise.

#### Precedência 11 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a && b`: Operador E lógico.

#### Precedência 12 (avaliados da esquerda para a direita):

- `a || b`: Operador OU lógico.

#### Precedência 13 (avaliados da direita para a esquerda):

- `a ? b : c`: Condicional ternário.

#### Precedência 14 (avaliados da direita para a esquerda):

- `a = b`: Atribuição.
- `a += b`: Atribuição com soma.
- `a -= b`: Atribuição com subtração.
- `a *= b`: Atribuição com multiplicação.
- `a /= b`: Atribuição com divisão.
- `a %= b`: Atribuição com resto de divisão.
- `a <<= b`: Atribuição com deslocamento de bits para a esquerda.
- `a >>= b`: Atribuição com deslocamento de bits para a direita.
- `a &= b`: Atribuição com E lógico.
- `a ^= b`: Atribuição com OU EXCLUSIVO lógico.
- `a |= b`: Atribuição com OU lógico.

#### Precedência 15 (avaliados por último, da esquerda para a direita):

- `a, b`: Separação de valores, resulta no último valor avaliado.

Answer (score 2):

Cada operador é diferente do outro. Não faria sentido existir operadores que fazem a mesma coisa.

Neste casos estamos falando de operadores relacionais que resultado em valores booleanos, ou seja, operadores que apenas respondem com dois estados, verdadeiro ou falso. Você usa os operadores relacionais para estabelecer relação entre dois valores. Com ele você está perguntando se esses valores são iguais (`==`), diferentes (`!=`), o primeiro maior que o segundo (`>`), o primeiro menor que o segundo (`<`), maior ou igual (`>=`), menor ou igual (`<=`).

`!=` é lido como **diferente**. Como o operador booleano `!` significa *not*, ou seja ele inverte o resultado booleano achou-se por bem representar o diferente como "não igual", ou seja um "! ==", simplificando `!=`.

Então em hipótese alguma o `!=` pode ser confundido com `<` que pergunta se um valor é **menor** que o outro.

Claro que se um valor é menor ele também é diferente, mas o contrário não é verdadeiro. Um valor pode ser diferente sendo tanto menor quanto maior que o outro valor comparado. Diferente significa diferença total. Menor é uma diferença em apenas um sentido.

Note que não há precedência entre os operadores relacionais. Será executado o que vier primeiro da esquerda para a direita. Exceto o `==` e `!=` que têm precedência menor.

Veja o [artigo na Wikipedia sobre o assunto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: `x < y != z` será avaliado como `(x < y) != z`. E em C o `x < y` pode ser avaliado como 0 ou 1, que pode ser igual ou diferente de `z`. Na maioria das vezes isso só serve para fazer programa ofuscado, mas já vi usos legítimos.

Comment: @Victor é verdade, fui confirmar agora. Às vezes confundo linguagens.

Comment: Na verdade há uma ordem sim entre os relacionais. `a < b == c > d` é avaliado como `(a < b) == (c > d)`. Novamente, isso só serve para escrever código ofuscado ou no mínimo confuso. O `==` e o `!=` são avaliados depois do `<`, `>`, `<=` e `>=`.

Answer (score 1):

**Operadores unários lógicos**

Operadores unários lógicos são aqueles que modificam somente um número, variável ou expressão, são eles:

- (**!**) negação, usado na frente de resultados booleanos, ao usar uma comparação 1==1 sabemos que ela resulta verdadeiro, ou 1, o operador negação inverte o resultado, ou seja !1==1 resulta em falso ou 0.

*Lembrando que 0 é como o C interpreta o falso, e 1 o verdadeiro, são sinônimos.*

**Operadores unários aritméticos**

- (**+**) e (**-**) o mais e menos unários representa o sinal de uma número, variável ou expressão. exemplo +5 -3 = +2

*Lembrando que o default é (+).*

**Operadores Binários aritméticos**

Operadores binários aritméticos são aqueles que executam uma operação matemática em uma expressão com números, variáveis e/ou expressões.

- 
- (*) Operador multiplicativo, executa uma multiplicação entre números variáveis ou expressões. 3 * 5 = 8.
- (/) Operador divisor, executa uma divisão matemática entre números variáveis ou expressões. 8 / 5 = 3.
- (%) Operador de módulo, executa a operação de congruência matemática, ou seja, 5%2 ele divide 5 por 2 e utiliza o resto da divisão, ou seja 5%2=1, ou 30%9 = 3
- (**+**) e (**-**) o mais e menos executam a soma e subtração matemática exemplo 5 -3 = 2 ou 5+3 = 8

**Comparadores Binários ou operadores relacionais**

o resultado de uma operação relacional é um se for verdadeiro ou 0 se for falso.

- (>) representa se um número, variável ou expressão é maior que o outro. 5>3 verdadeiro

  ```
  int a=5,b=3;
  if(a>b)
  {
     //isso é executado;
  }
  ```

*- (>=) o mesmo que o de cima mas se for igual ele resulta em verdadeiro*

```
int a=5,b=5;
if(a>b)
{
   //isso não é executado;
}
```

---

```
int a=5,b=5;
if(a>=b)
    {
//isso é executado;
}
```

- (<) representa se um número, variável ou expressão é menor que o outro. 5>3 verdadeiro

int a=5,b=3;
    if(b

*- (<=) o mesmo que o de cima mas se for igual ele resulta em verdadeiro*

```
    int a=5,b=5;
if(b<a)
{
   //isso não é executado;
}
```

---

```
int a=5,b=5;
if(a<=b)
    {
//isso é executado;
}
```

- (==) comparador lógico de igualdade, se isso for igual aquilo.

  if(5==5)
  {
     //isso é executado
  }
- (!=) negação da igualdade, diferença. se isso for diferente que aquilo

  if(5!=5)
  {
     //isso não é executado
  }

**Operadores lógicos**
&& e lógico
|| ou lógico

tabela de prioridades, procedencia e associatividade
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]