# Por que uma expressão com resto e multiplicação está dando como resultado errado?

Tags: c, matemática, operadores

Por que esse código está dando como resultado -2 e não 7?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 main()
 {
   printf("%i\n", 105 % 3*4 - 3*4 % (101 / 10));
   system("pause");
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu fiz assim e deu 7:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%i\n", 105 % (3 * 4) - (3 * 4) % (101 / 10));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cWlRnf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mecljfsz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/Precedence.c).

Provavelmente interpretou a expressão sem considerar a [precedência e associatividade dos operadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40180/101). O operador de resto tem a mesma precedência da multiplicação e associatividade pela esquerda, então em uma expressão com os dois operadores o que aparecer primeiro será executado. Para aumentar a precedência de um operador deve usar o operador de parênteses que possui prioridade bem alta.

O segundo par de parênteses não é necessário, coloquei só para ajudar enxergar melhor a separação. O último par, que já existia, resolve o problema de precedência que poderia haver.